# How to use two internet connections and set one for download and the other for upload?

Tags: networking, router, internet, bandwidth

I have two internet Connections.

1. DSL 5 mbps **Download** / 0.5 mbps **Upload** (unlimited bandwidth)
2. LTE 10 mbps **Download** / 5 mbps **Upload** (10GB limited Daily Bandwidth)

I want to use both connections on my computer but would like to use the LTE connection for uploads only.

This is because I work from home and work with videos, I need to take advantage of the higher upload speed.

There are no other options for ISP and other plans in my area so I am stuck with these connections.

It would be ideal if I can switch between combining the two so I can have faster internet and download and limiting the bandwidth of the LTE connection for when I need to upload finished work.

If it's possible to do this from just my PC without special equipment, it would really help me out.

My connections both have their own routers, they are connecting via (1) the on board gigabit Ethernet and the other (2) is connecting via an Ethernet to USB module.

Worst case: is if the above isn't possible, if I can switch between the two connections while having both connected and not physically switching LAN cables and only using one Ethernet card. I can live with this until I can save up for a router that would be able to do the load management.

TIA for the help

Comment: Which Operating System are you using?

Comment: It's windows 10

Answer (score 0):

The easiest quick and dirty solution is:

```
route add <host where you wanna upload to> gw <gateway ip of the LTE connection>
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to add that I'm a super newbie when it comes to these things. Where would I do the above and when you say host, I add the site of each place i need to upload to? Like Dropbox, hightail, and YouTube? Thanks so much!

Comment: You would need to execute this as privileged user for each host you want your LTE to be used for. This means running something like `sudo route add myuploadpage.com gw 192.168.1.1` where myuploadpage.com is the target of your data and 192.168.1.1 is the Gateway which is used by the LTE Interface. You would need to reexecute this after a reboot. Use `sudo route -a` to get an overview over your routing table. Take this advice with a grain of salt, because I just wrote, what I think is right (without asserting correctness :))

Comment: I was able to add the routes but I don't see anything happening. I tested doing an upload and the speed is the same for the destination that is not routed and one that is. It seems they are still using the DSL connection.

Not sure if I did anything wrong through. Also I need to make sure once I get this to work is that only upload traffic goes through this route. Meaning if I route dropbox I want downloads to go through the DSL (unlimited bandwidth) and only upload to go via the LTE (limited 10GB daily bandwidth)